LinearProgressIndicator appears split in two in androidx.compose.material3 version 1.3.0
I am using LinearProgressIndicator in my Kotlin Compose project. After upgrading androidx.compose.material3 from version 1.2.0 to 1.3.0, I noticed that the LinearProgressIndicator no longer displays as expected. It should appear as a single, continuous progress bar, but instead, it looks split in two, with an extra dot appearing at the end.
The code is as follows:
@Composable
fun CustomProgressBar() {
    LinearProgressIndicator(
        progress = { 0.5f },
        trackColor = Color.Gray,
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(200.dp)
            .height(15.dp),
        color = Color.Blue,
        strokeCap = StrokeCap.Round,
    )
}

Has anyone encountered this issue, or is there a known workaround to fix the display of LinearProgressIndicator in version 1.3.0?

Can you please post the answer that you originally shared on the Staging Ground question? Happy to upvote it then.

Agree. Issue seems to be with LinearProgressIndicator when strokeCap is Round, applying negative gapSize fixes the issue

I found the source of this issue: androidx.compose.material3 1.3.0 added two new parameters to LinearProgressIndicator: gapSize and drawStopIndicator.
This is explained in the KDoc documentation as follows:
gapSize - size of the gap between the progress indicator and the track
drawStopIndicator - lambda that will be called to draw the stop indicator
gapSize: Dp = ProgressIndicatorDefaults.LinearIndicatorTrackGapSize,

drawStopIndicator: DrawScope.() -> Unit = {
        drawStopIndicator(
            drawScope = this,
            stopSize = ProgressIndicatorDefaults.LinearTrackStopIndicatorSize,
            color = color,
            strokeCap = strokeCap
        )
},

When I gave the gapSize and drawStopIndicator Indicator parameters, I got the appearance I wanted and solved this problem.
LinearProgressIndicator(
        progress = { 0.5f },
        trackColor = Color.Gray,
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(200.dp)
            .height(15.dp),
        color = Color.Blue,
        strokeCap = StrokeCap.Round,
        gapSize = (-15).dp,
        drawStopIndicator = {}
    )

When we give the drawStopIndicator an empty function {}, we can hide the point at the end of the progress bar.
When strokeCap ​​= StrokeCap.Round, giving gapSize = 0 does not provide a solution, it needs to be given a negative value. If strokeCap ​​= StrokeCap.Butt or strokeCap ​​= StrokeCap.Square is set, giving gapSize = 0 will work.

The round gap will not work,
It is new material 3 design you can customize like this,

            LinearProgressIndicator(
                color = Color.Blue, 
                trackColor = Color.Gray, 
                progress = { 0.70f },
                gapSize = 0.dp,
                strokeCap = StrokeCap.Square,
                drawStopIndicator = {},
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(24.dp))


The user requires strokeCap to be Round, not square
